# How to get the right index for a delayed trigger?

Tags: javascript

Following problem: I have an angular module with `$http.get` to get some google coordinates. This function triggers another function. This function again triggers another function. It will all make sense in a moment.

Angular Module:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('wmw', []);
        myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            //Angular Method
            $scope.getTargetCords = function (data) {
                $http.get(data).success(function (response) {
                    $(document).triggerHandler('my_func:data-received', [response]);
                });
            };
        });
```

onSucess:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    currentLat = position.coords.latitude ;
    currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
    for(i = 0; i<locations.length;i++){
        var destUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' + locations[i][ 'street' ] + ',' + locations[i][ 'city' ] + ',Deutschland' + '&sensor=true';
        var MyAngularScope = angular.element($("#MainCtrlId")).scope();
        MyAngularScope.getTargetCords('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' + locations[i][ 'street' ] + ',' + locations[i][ 'city' ] + ',Deutschland' + '&sensor=true');
    }   
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

The two triggers:

```
$(document).on('my_func:data-received', function(event, response) {
    map[s] = response;
    s++;
    if(s === locations.length){
        $(document).triggerHandler('allData');
    }
});

$(document).on('allData', function(){
    var thecoords = [];
    var distance = [];
    $('#filter-list').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        thecoords[0] = $(map[i]).find('lat').first().text();
        thecoords[1] = $(map[i]).find('lng').first().text();
        distance[i] = calculateDistance(currentLat, currentLng, thecoords[0], thecoords[1]);
        locations[i]['distance'] = distance[i];
    }
    locations.sort(function(a,b) 
        { return a.distance - b.distance;}
    );
    for(var i = 0;i < locations.length; i++){
        distance[i] = locations[i]['distance'].toFixed(2);
        distance[i] += ' KM';
        locations[i]['distance'] = distance[i];
    }
    $('.loading').hide();
    for(var i = 0; i<=5; i++){
        addItemToList(locations[i]);        
    }
});
```

What's happening? With those functions I retrieve the current location, the dest location and calculate the difference in KM via a lat./long. calc function which I found on the web. `.loading` is just a div with "Calculating route..." and a transparent grey background. So once everything is finished, The "Distance" of every route will change to the calculated distance.

The problem with this: in my ".on('my_func:data-received')" I am using the variable "s" which is 0 at the start. In my logic I thought, that this would then put the responses one after another in my "map". But now I realised, that the "data-received" are not called one after another, but each time when data is retrieved. So when locations[0] is calling the `$http.get` and then after this locations[1] is calling the `$http.get`, it could happen, that locations[1] retrieves the data earlier. How could I have my "s" always be the right number? So that when I have locations[1] calling `$http.get` map[1] will be locations[1] response?

My head is exploding, as I cant find a solution to this problem, although it seems to be so basic.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: that stuff is asynchronous. you're calling `getTargetCoords` in a loop. have a look at the angular promise library, maybe? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: But it works. I am retrieving the right distances, just in the wrong order...

Comment: Exactly. Calls to web services are never reliably returned in the order they're called (the loop), it just depends on which one was the fastest, which could be different every time. Promises could solve this.

Comment: Woops, wanted to delete that comment. The problem is, that angular is only used for this one function. I know it kinda sucks to do so, but the app was already finished and then it was desired to display the current distance, so I had to implement angular. So all of the stuff is written in js and just one function is written in this angular app. So to use locations variable in that app, I would have to write all my javascript code to be running in angular also. Is there another way to pass in a number and give this variable to my trigger, so the trigger "knows" which location is the current?

Comment: So you don't like promises? Your trigger can't know which url came in in what order. Dunno by heart but I'm guessing the response contains the url which had the location. Can you search your original array for that?

Comment: It's not about liking promises. The idea behind promises is the right one, but it would mean really much effort to rewrite so much of my .js, so I am searching for the shortest solution. The response SHOULD in fact contain that information! That idea is great. Would you write it in an answer? Then I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure. Tried to fresh it out a little. I'm on my phone, makes adding code hard... I'll review tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since restructuring your application is not an option, another reasonably quick way of getting the right order is mapping the response data to the original array. The response contains the url which is built using data from the array which might give you what you need.